# Default SharedPreferences don't save values

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, default

I have this class:

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtil {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

private static final String PRODUCTION_MODE_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON = "www.exemplo.com/json";

//configuration keys
private static final String KEY_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON = "KEY_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON";

public SharedPreferenceUtil(Context context){
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

private void initializeDefaultAppConfigurationValues(){
    prefs.edit().putString(KEY_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON, PRODUCTION_MODE_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON);
    prefs.edit().commit();
}

public Configuration getConfiguration() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    initializeDefaultAppConfigurationValues();

    configuration.setChecklistGetURL(prefs.getString(KEY_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON,""));

    return configuration;
}

}
```

When I save the values ​​in row: prefs.edit () commit ().. It returned true. When I try to read the value in: prefs.getString (KEY_URL_GET_CHECKLIST_JSON, ""). It returned "" as if the value had not been saved.

Could someone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below link it will useful for you

[Sharedpreference store andr retrival](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/63/example_preferences_in_android)

Answer (score 0):

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

you forgot about `static`

```
 private static SharedPreferences prefs;
```

it should be ONE for all exemplars